# VirtualBox issues in Fedora 15

Tags: virtualbox, fedora-15

I installed VirtualBox with the RPM from http://virtualbox.org ; but when I tried to setup and run a VM it said that the VirtualBox service was not started (`vboxdrv`) and told me to `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`; but that failed to install the driver.

What should I do now? Reinstalling the driver through `vboxdrv setup` isn't working, `vbox restart` didn't do anything; should I remove VirtualBox and try reinstalling it? If so, how? I'm kinda new to Linux, is there an uninstall utility for Fedora?

Output of `vboxdrv setup` (abbreviated)

```
Installing new VirtualBox modules via DKMS [  FAILED  ]
(trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules      [  FAILED  ]
```

Comment: Can you expand on it failing? Any errors?

Comment: do you have DKMS installed? (yum install dkms maybe)

Comment: Or you could try to install virtualbox from Fedora's packages if available. yum install virtualbox-ose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `vboxdrv` needs to have `gcc` and `dkms` installed; I had neither.

After installing `dkms` and `gcc`, it worked.